# Handle millions of Requests between Java and Oracle DB

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I have a java application, that tries to match data between two different tables on the db. Currently we are using a stored procedure, and we are limited to a single thread. We are looking to speed things up, by developing a java application to run in multiple threads. The best way i can thing of, a opening a cursor, on the source table, and distributing the read records to different thread, where each thread queries the database for the matching record. However, with a large number of records (~ 2 million), we are looking at 2 million requests to the database, with the same query, and different values, is their a way, i can keep the connection open, or anything to make things as fast as possible?

Comment: i believe you will find the performance very poor compared to letting the database do these matches... that is after all what databases are designed to do.  Perhaps spend energy on optimizing the database before trying this approach.

Comment: If you were to actually show the relevant CREATE TABLE statements and some representative INSERT statements, and describe the rules for the matching, I'll be someone could show you how to do it in a single SQL statement that will run much faster than row--by-row (slow-by-slow) cursor processing.

Comment: *"The best way i can thing of, a opening a cursor"* - when it comes to DB, open cursor is last resort. Best way would be **not** opening cursor